# UI scroll View Help

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, xcode4

Hi i need help with UIScrollView..
i m loading tens views onto my scroll view.. am loading them correctly.. I m Using IBoutlet for showing scroll view.
now the problem is i want my scroll view to reset to nil on disappearing and reappearing of mine view..

I m making its delegate to nil. and releasing mine array in which the images are stored.. To make a scroll view nil that is to delete all the subviews of a scroll view do i have to reinitialize the scroll view.. 
Sorry for my english.. and please any help or hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just remove your scrollview subViews and add subview when you want dont need to reinitialize

```
NSArray *scrollViewSubViews=[yourScrollView subviews];
for(UIView *view in scrollViewSubViews)
{
    [view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

If you wanna Add a view just

```
[yourScrollView addSubview:yourimageViews];
```